# Running PhoneRTC Demo

Tags: android, webrtc, cordova-plugins, phonertc

I am trying to run the phoneRTC demo, I hae build the android demo app and have a signalling server running but when I run the client app on android all I get is a blank screen.

these are the steps I have taken:

```
npm install -g cordova bower grunt-cli

git clone https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc.git

ionic create phonertc-ionic

cp -R phonertc\demo\client\* phonertc-ionic\

cd phonertc-ionic
npm install
bower install

cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
cordova plugin add https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc.git

cordova platform add android

cd ../phonertc/demo/server
npm install
node index.js
```

change server details in phonertc-ionic/app/scripts/signaling.js to:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://my_server_ip:3000/');
```

and run the following in phonertc-ionic:

```
grunt build --force

cp -R app/* www/

cordova build android
```

My signalling server is running but when I try to hit the port via a browser I get the following message:

```
Error: ENOENT, stat '/home/server/index.html'
```

and when I run the app on my phone I just get a blank screen.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, turns out there was a bug in the grunt version I was using, using an older version or manually adding the libraries instead of using grunt worked.

Comment: Can you please share detailed answer for your fix?
what version of grunt did you use?  what is the manual step

Comment: Me problemo is that with just the signaling server (everything running on my LAN), I can connect and see my different devices (after "Login") but when I call, the caller just gets stuck on "Calling to <name of the callee>" whilst the callee can actually answer the call but the screen just shows "Call in progress"

Comment: @PU2014 be more specific man then only ppl can get something out of your comment otherwise your answer is useless